# Pd.DF dropping rows on datetime hourly data

Tags: python

I have the following issue (probably an easy one but I'm still learning).

My data has a time interval of 15minutes and runs for a couple of days.

[image: Here and example of the data.index]

Can anyone help me how I can drop all the rows except for the 15 minutes starting at 17:00 each day?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself and it might be usefull for others.
The code I used is the following.

df= df.drop(df[df.index.hour != 17].index)

df= df.drop(df[df.index.minute != 00].index)

This drops all the rows which are not 17:00

I'm aware that this possibly isn't the cleanest code but it does the job, cleaner alternatives are still welcome though.